# Unable to change the color of the status bar in the TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-studio, colors, android-tablayout

I want to change the color of the status bar in the `TabLayout` but I'm getting an error?

Screenshot of the code with error
http://s3.picofile.com/file/8370099418/Screenshot_from_2019_08_20_14_57_39.jpg

```
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().getStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this , R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                }
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Yellow));
                tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.Yellow));
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getWindow().getStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.YellowDark));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Color.parseColor("#4CAF50") use color like this

Comment: use setStatusBarColor() instead of getStatusBarColor().

Comment: Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
    statusBarColor = window.getStatusBarColor();
    window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_mode_status_bar));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have to use
 `tabLayout.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.YellowDark))`

Answer (score 0):

Java:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Window window = this.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }
```

Kotlin:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            val window = this.window
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            window.statusBarColor = this.resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
        }
```